# How can I prevent Backspace from taking me back to the previous page while I use the login box

Tags: .net, javascript, authentication, navigation, backspace

the login box is in the header of the website, availalbe on all pages.
I'm using a javascript :

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
       history.forward();
```

Which solves the issue of the backspace in the login box.
But while I'm browsing the rest of the website, I can use backspace to see the previous page, I'd have to use the navigation menu only. How can I solve that issue ?

Comment: What are you using as a login box? An `<input type="text">`? If so browsers shouldn't be redirecting you to the previous page when you use the backspace key. Can you provide some code that shows the login box and/or how it is created?

Comment: What JavaScript library are you using?

Comment: It's actually a .NET application, not an html input box precisely. It's an ASP Panel... If I do write a good username, a good valid username...it will bring three little boxes of 1 character each, with an algorythm, it asks you a position of a character of your password. . . then you're IN. Thing is, I placed the <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">  history.forward(); it does it well, can't hit back...but I can't hit back in the rest of the pages of the site.!! that's all :)

Answer (score 3):

Try this JavaScript

```
<script for="document" event=onkeydown>

// Check if this is a Backspace
 if (window.event.keyCode == 8)
 {
    // Cancel backspace if not in a text element
    if(document.activeElement.type != "text")
    {
        window.event.returnValue=false;
    }
 }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

A webpage changing the key bindings of the browser is a controversial topic, as this violates the principle of the least surprise (which should be familiar to an UX designer). Also, not all browsers have this key mapping (Bksp -> Go back).

That said: you can try capturing the key events, as described e.g. [here](http://www.geekpedia.com/tutorial138_Get-key-press-event-using-JavaScript.html) and cancelling the event propagation. Not sure if this is possible for all keys, so you'd have to try and see.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I'll check the link you posted. 

About the User Experience subject, the stakeholders, owners of the company, the people who give me a paycheck are the end users as well, and regarding of this specific system which is just for them and for a limited amount of clients, they REQUIRE that feature. I understand your concern tho. They're very keyboard oriented people, as this is a finances website. Sometimes there's nothing to do about certain things, no other option, if they want that, I'll give them that.

Comment: @UXdesigner: Yeah, I understand...having the client who effectively says "but I *want* my website to be ugly and unusable, make it so!" is painful :-|

Comment: The site itself looks amazing. But user testing revelead that as we use three separate character for password boxes , and if someone places a mistaken key, and hits backspace, itbrings you back to the previous page, not to the previous field.  Most people don't know the Shift-Tab key combination. that's all.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a proper HTML text input box and the focus is on it then backspace will not take the user back. If you're not using a proper HTML input box then I suggest you do so. Browsers handle this stuff for you.

Comment: It's actually a .NET application, not an html input box precisely.
It's an ASP Panel... If I do write a good username, a good valid username...it will bring three little boxes of 1 character each, with an algorythm, it asks you a position of a character of your password. . . then you're IN.
Thing is, I placed the <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
       history.forward(); 
it does it well, can't hit back...but I can't hit back in the rest of the pages of the site.!! that's all :)